# Complex Power Series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

So, I'm trying to find the power series of ${1\over 1-z+z^2} around the point z=0.$ After some rather easy algebra I've determined the expression to be $${1\over z-(1+i\sqrt{3})/2} {1\over z-(1-i\sqrt{3})/2}$$ So I tried to use the ${1\over 1-x}$ power series as basis. Thing is, the result that I obtain is completely different from the one the solutions provide, so if anyone could clarify the oprocedure I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: You can only use the define article 'the' for a power series around a point.

Comment: @user166271 Please "A power series" ... around which point?

Comment: Aroudn z=0 sorry, forgot to mention that :p

Comment: Add that information to the question and follow Mhenni's hint.

Comment: I tried following the hint but I get the inverse of what I should have a I don't think I'm making an algebraic mistake. I get 1/(1-z+z^2)=isqrt(3)/(z-(isqrt(3)+1)/2)-isqrt(3)/(z-(1-isqrt(3)/2). From there I put the necessary terms aside so that I get for instance isqrt(3)/((isqrt(3)+1)/2)*(1/1-(2z/(isqrt(3)+1)) and from there it's just plain old substition - but it gives me the inverse of the supposed answer. Any further hints would be more than welcome at this point

Comment: @user166271 The answer should look like $$1+z-z^3-z^4+z^6+z^7-z^9-z^{10}+z^{12}+z^{13}-z^{15}-z^{16}+z^{18}+\ldots$$ Is this what you're getting? Is this the answer you were given?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Assuming $|-z|<1,$

$$\frac1{1-z+z^2}=\frac{1+z}{1+z^3}=(1+z)(1+z^3)^{-1}$$

Comment: If I follow through with that I get something which is entirely different to the solution. The problem is right now I'm getting the inverse of what is supposed to appear, and I can't for the life of me figure out why since I've retraced the calculations to make sure I did not commit an error

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can use partial fractions then use the geometric series.